# How to check for 30sec if file in folder exist?

Tags: qt, file, qt5

I want to check if in a Folder are a json-File called "test.json" for 30 sec.

I have in Qt a Button, which execute a python skript --> this skript create the test.json.

When I clicked the Button now i get the file successfully.

How can I checked if a file is in a Folder for 30 sec?

Any Idea?

Comment: Use a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html)

Comment: what you need to check? if the file is there at least 30 seconds, or at latest after 30 seconds???

Comment: I need to check if the file are at latest after 30 seconds are exist.
If not, i answer with an Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `QTimer`

with singleshot = true and interval to 30 000

```
t = new QTimer(this);
t->setSingleShot(true);
t->setInterval(30 * 1000);
connect(t, &QTimer::timeout, [](){
    qDebug() << "is the file already there: " << QFile::exists("/home/pw/file.txt");});
t->start();
```